# How do I set material only for one object in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I have two 3D objects, and I need to set material only on one of them using `glMaterial` function. How can I accomplish this?

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <cmath>


const int width = 1200, height = 600;


float xValue = 0.0;
float position = 0.0;
float angle = 0.0;

float shininess[] = { 1.0 };
float color[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.8 };


void init(void);
void display(void);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(85, 75);
    glutCreateWindow("3D объекты - освещение");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    float lightAmbient[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 };
    float lightDiffuse[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 };
    float lightSpecular[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 };
    float lightPosition[] = { -10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-10.0, 10.0, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
}

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0.0, 0.0, width, height);

    xValue += 0.01;
    position = 5.0*cos(xValue);
    angle = 270.0*sin(xValue);

    glLineWidth(3);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(position, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, color);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, color);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, color);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shininess);

        glutWireTorus(1, 2, 35, 35);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-position, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

        glutSolidTorus(0.5, 3.5, 35, 35);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is a state engine. Each state is kept until it is changed again, even beyond frames. For instance you can enable and disable lighting before drawing an object:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
// darw object 1

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
// draw object 2
```

ALike the material settings can be set for each object individually, before drawing the object:

```cpp
glMaterialfv(...);
// darw object 1

glMaterialfv(...);
// draw object 2
```